# Android development on windows or linux?

Tags: android

Which OS is better for developing android applications? I tried in windows but the emulator takes forever to load...

Is it better in linux?

Comment: This question seems to be dangerously subjective

Answer (score 13):

- The emulator is fairly slow on all operating systems.
- Linux might have an edge for "obscure case" development (especially for large or intricate projects with the ndk) since the desktop environment better matches that of the device itself and is the natural home of the toolchain.  But if you get stuck, you can run the obscure tools in a linux VM.
- The SDK and on the surface NDK are intended to be platform neutral, so ideally the developers' personal preference or organizational support capabilities would dominate the choice - ie, the intent is that windows shops can do android while remaining windows shops.
- Android projects should be entirely portable - unless you rely on additional authoring tools, you should be able to change development host operating systems fairly easily.  Though any time you switch machines you need to decide if you are going to move the signing keys or not.

Answer (score 3):

The android emulator is very slow on both windows and linux.

If you don't have a test device you can try to download and run the x86 version of android into a Virtual Machine (you can find tutorials for that on the web).