# Does SDK from Windows 10 work in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, sdk

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 for a month.Now i need to install android studio. When i try to install, it ask me to show the path for SDK. I've a SDK folder from windows 10 where I've installed android studio before. Now can i use that SDK or I've to download a new one for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Each Operational System have their own SDK package.

As you can see in the Google's Android [download section](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads), there are different versions with different filesizes.

If you go to the Windows SDK directory (AppData/Local/Android/sdk) you will see some ".exe" files, which implies that some funcionalities can't be used on Unix systems.

For more SDK features differences check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039529/are-there-dfferences-between-the-windows-and-linux-versions-of-the-android-sdk).